# compilation error in objective-c file

Tags: objective-c, c

I am developing a command line app which uses obj-c and c files together. In my obj-c file (say x.m), I use a struct which uses an interface and the interface uses a struct. This is easily handled in C++ with forward declarations but I need obj-c in my app.

I was wondering if someone can please shed some light on what I doing wrong.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct mystruct_s
{
  ...
  ....
} mystruct;

struct abc ; 
@interface abcDelegate:NSObject {
     @public
          struct abc *abc; 
} 
@end

struct abc 
{
     mystruct b
     abcDelegate *abcdelegate; 
};
```

I get the following error error:

```
expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘mystruct’
```

Comment: and where mystruct is defined ?

Comment: mystruct is defined above abcDelegate

Comment: are you using this .h file in m. or .mm file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot `;`

should be

```
struct abc 
{
     mystruct b;
     abcDelegate *abcdelegate; 
};
```

If using .m file you must use c-style structs. such as

```
typedef struct mystruct_
{
...
} mystruct;
```

or

```
struct abc 
{
     struct mystruct b;
     abcDelegate *abcdelegate; 
};
```

If you want structs just like in c++ change your file extension to .mm to support c++

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Change the code to look like this:

```
struct abc 
{
     mystruct b;
     abcDelegate *abcdelegate; 
};

@interface abcDelegate:NSObject {
     @public
          struct abc *abc; 
} 
@end
```